# In Azure resource.pipelines.pipeline, why are both "pipeline" and "source" properties required?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to learn more about azure pipelines and I'm pretty green. In one of my company's pipelines, we have a property like:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 1234
    source: pipeline-name
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - master
      - refs/heads/master
```

If I go to our Pipelines page, I can see "pipeline-name" as an option, and if I click into it, I see the id (1234) in the URL. (Names and ids changed to protect the innocent.) As far as I can tell, they are 1:1.

I am uncertain why I need to specify both `pipeline` (id) *and* `source`. Providing an id makes sense to me, but `source` is required and only a "valid pipeline name" seems to work. So why are both required? Is there a way to have 2 pipelines with the same id, or 2 ids with the same pipeline? Or is this just a weird requirement that doesn't really make sense?

The "What did you try and what were you expecting?" kills me sometimes, but: I tried googling and expected to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1234` is not the id of the pipeline. Maybe someone took the id and put it there but you can change it to anything you want and all will work. But if you change the source you will change the pipeline to which this resource is referring to.

Take a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops):

```
# app-ci YAML pipeline
# We are setting up a pipeline resource that references the security-lib-ci
# pipeline and setting up a pipeline completion trigger so that our app-ci
# pipeline runs when a run of the security-lib-ci pipeline completes
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: securitylib # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: security-lib-ci # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    project: FabrikamProject # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
    trigger: true # Run app-ci pipeline when any run of security-lib-ci completes

steps:
- bash: echo "app-ci runs after security-lib-ci comple
```

> - `pipeline: securitylib` specifies the name of the pipeline resource. Use the label defined here when referring to the pipeline resource from other parts of the pipeline, such as when using pipeline resource variables or downloading artifacts.
> - `source: security-lib-ci` specifies the name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource. You can retrieve a pipeline's name from the Azure DevOps portal in several places, such as the Pipelines landing page. By default, pipelines are named after the repository that contains the pipeline. To update a pipeline's name, see Pipeline settings.

Comment: LOL ok. Yeah that's what I was missing alright. `pipeline` is a label, but `source` is the actual identifier. Thank you very much!

Comment: What if I have my source pipeline in a folder? I tried source: \MyFolderName\MyPipeline-CI but it is not being triggered when my MyPipeline-CI finishes building.